# FileNotFoundError in Jupyter Notebook, even though the file is there

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, librosa

This was all written in Jupyter Notebook online. What supposed to happen, is the first line of the code is a command that converts some file in the folder labeled "capstone" into an mp4. This works fine, however the problem I'm running into is a "FileNotFoundError", and I'm not sure why this is happening, as I check to see if the file is there, it is in fact there.

```
!ffmpeg -i recording1.mov -q:v 0 output.mp4

import librosa
audio_path = '/home/gentry/capstone/output1.mp4'
x , sr = librosa.load(audio_path)
print(type(x), type(sr))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import librosa.display
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 5))

librosa.display.waveplot(x, sr=sr)

X = librosa.stft(x)
Xdb = librosa.amplitude_to_db(abs(X))
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 5))

librosa.display.specshow(Xdb, sr=sr, x_axis='time', y_axis='hz') 

librosa.display.specshow(Xdb, sr=sr, x_axis='time', y_axis='log')
```

The output should be a visualized waveform of a sound, and two subsequent Fourier transform graphs.
I can provide additional details as requested

Comment: could you run this command in one of your cells ```ls``` , aslo I noticed ffmpeg output is named ```output.mp4``` while your audio path contains ```ouptut1.mp4```

Comment: @kareem_emad that's a typo on my part, `output1.mp4` should be there, but even when it is, it still does not work properly. Also what does this `ls` do? I've tried executing it and it didn't work. I'm still new to Jupyter Notebook, but not coding in general.

Comment: sorry for late response -different time zones-, the command !ls should show you the available files in the current directory, the output file should one of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually just a simple mistake of pathways being different, as this was provided to me by a professor, so `audio_path = '/home/gentry/capstone/output1.mp4'` should actually just be `audio_path = './output1.mp4'`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I will just make small modifications to your code to make all paths relative so the error may not be for wrong manual string path you wrote.

First I ran this command as is:

```
!ffmpeg -i recording1.mov -q:v 0 output.mp4
```

then to make sure that I have the output right

```
!ls | grep output
```

that should give you

```
output.mp4
```

Then as I know that the file is in the same directory as my notebook, I will make the load command as follows

```
import librosa
audio_path = './output.mp4'
x , sr = librosa.load(audio_path)
print(type(x), type(sr))
```

That works perfectly and loads the audio component, my figs maybe totally different than yours as I'm using some random video not your input one as it's not provided

[image]

Comment: This does help explain what you are doing better, but I found out that my pathway is different, because this code was provided to me by my professor I'm working with. As stupid as it sounds (and as I am), `audio_path = '/home/gentry/capstone/output1.mp4` should actually just be `audio_path = ./output1.mp4` in my case. Simple mistake on my part, but thank you for helping